# Incorrect image display in QGraphicsScene, PyQt

Tags: python, qt, opencv, pyqt, qgraphicsscene

I'm faced with a strange problem while I'd like to display an image with a `QGraphicsScene` inside a `QGraphicsView` in `PyQt`.

For some image files it works well,

[image: image1]
[image: display of image1]

but for others it seems wrong,

[image: image2]
[image: display of image2]

i think maybe it's related with the format of the images? If so, what should I do?

Related part of codes are as follows, thanks for your kind help :D

```
image = cv2.imread(str(file_path))
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
height, width = image.shape[:2]

self.scene.clear()
self.frame = QtGui.QImage(image.data, width, height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.frame))
self.scene.update()
self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had absolutely same issue, but it was `C++` project, so I think that my solution will work for you too. Consider next code:

```
   QString sss = "path";
   cv::Mat img = cv::imread(sss.toStdString());

   cv::cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGR2RGB);//in your code cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   QImage image1((uchar*)img.data,img.cols,img.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);
   //in your code QtGui.QImage(image.data, width, height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
   //same problem
   QPixmap px1(QPixmap::fromImage(image1));
   ui->label_2->setPixmap(px1);
```

Solution:

```
//...
QImage image1((uchar*)img.data,img.cols,img.rows,img.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);
//...
```

As you can see, I added one more argument: `img.step` `( int bytesPerLine )` in `Qt` documentation. So try to do the same in your `python` app.

Comment: Thanks for your edit and kindly answer :)  
After trail and search, I think that I've came with an **python** version solution, which works for the Format_RGB888 images. The parameter widthStep (bytes per line) is set to 3*widthOfImage:  
`widthStep = width * 3`
`self.frame = QtGui.QImage(image.data, width, height, widthStep, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)`